# Fast-forward branch in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, fast-forward

For some reason, I have following situation:

[image]

Now I want to get rid of `default_2` and fast-forward `default` to rev 89. But when I do

```
hg up -r default
hg transplant 61:89
```

or

```
hg transplant -b default_2
```

Mercurial (1.8.2+20110401) just updates my working copy to rev 89. With `mq` extension it looks like I have to specify all intermediate revisions one-by-one.

So the questions are:

1. Why doesn’t `transplant` work? (It’s recommended here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseProject#When_rebase_is_not_allowed)
2. Is there a way to fast-forward without much pain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Mercurial Queues, you can:

```
hg qinit
hg qimport -r 61:89
hg qpop -a           # unapply all patches
hg up default        # return to your default branch
hg qpush -a          # apply all patches on default
hg qfinish -a        # move applied patches into repo history
```

**NOTE:** This assumes that revisions 61:89 have not been pushed to a public repo.  The given `mq` commands will modify history.  If these revisions have already been pushed, then it would be best to simply close the `default2` branch and then merge `default2` into `default`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works, didn’t find anywhere in the docs that qimport understands ranges.

Comment: @Nikita: You are welcome.  In newer versions of Mercurial (>=v1.7), the `-r` option supports a functional language for selecting sets of revisions.  See `hg help revsets` for details (http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets).  Also, if my answer was good, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Wow, thanks again! By the way, don’t you know what’s the problem with `transplant`? Official documentation recommends it here: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseProject#When_rebase_is_not_allowed

Comment: @Nikita: I just started looking at that now.  It is not working for me at the moment either, but I have an unstable version of Mercurial installed.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 hg branch --force default
```

it recreate new branch named default

Answer (score 0):

As of Mercurial 2.0 you can use the *graft* command (built-in command largely replacing the *transplant* extension):

```
hg graft 61:89
```

See also a related question on [differences between graft and transplant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8009632/396967).

Note that the reason Mercurial doesn't support actual fast-forwards a la Git between named branches is that the branch name is part of the Mercurial commit object. See also this [article detailing the Mercurial branch model](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/#branching-with-named-branches).