# Mercurial - transplanting changesets from different branch (using TortoiseHg)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm maintainig a project with two heads which are pretty much alike so i thought it would be possible to just transplant a changeset from one branch to the other.
But this sometimes fails because the code to change is on a different line and i end up with .rej file.

What are my options from that point on now?

Ist there any visual interface that can help me fix this - like when resolving a merge?

Can i tell `transplant` to ignore line numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mercurial 2.0 introduced the [Graft command](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#graft).

Like explained in the following SO answer : [Graft vs. Transplant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009632/graft-vs-transplant), Graft uses the internal three way merge mechanism instead of the patch one, so it is able to better handle the kind of problems you're describing. You can also have a look on this question : [mercurial: how to cherry pick during merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356436/mercurial-how-to-cherry-pick-during-merging).

Comment: I was not aware of the difference between graft and transplant. Thanks, that really helps a lot!