# Mercurial: shelve vs. mq

Tags: mercurial, shelving

I have been using mercurial for a little while, and have been slowly learning it's features. A while ago I learned about shelves, and have been using them happily. Now I am trying to understand patch queues, but from what I read, they sound very similar to shelves. I can save my work without actually committing it, switch branches if I want, and later come back to it. How do these two differ?

Note: I saw this: [Mercurial: graft vs. record vs. qrecord vs. shelve vs. transplant vs. dirstate vs. queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631273/mercurial-graft-vs-record-vs-qrecord-vs-shelve-vs-transplant-vs-dirstate-v), but didn't find that it addressed this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Patch queues have a superset of the features of shelves.  In addition to setting aside work in progress, the major difference is that applying a patch creates a changeset, instead of only changing the working directory.  Keeping the patches distinct enables other workflows, such as these from [the book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html):

- "Refreshing a patch" iteratively, giving you checkpoints you can roll back to.
- "Stacking and tracking patches", multiple applied patches don't get mixed together.

Comment: Good answer! I would add to the list "reorder patches". At least I often end up doing this.